# Typeorm: disable transactions by default

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

When I do any update/insert I have queries in a log file

```
START TRANSACTION
UPDATE/INSERT table SET .....
COMMIT
```

Is there any way to disable typeorm transactions by default for all queries?

Comment: I think it depends on which API you're using

Comment: Why do you want to disable transactions? Do you understand that even if you were to skip the START TRANSACTION/COMMIT, that there would still be a transaction (assuming your tables are InnoDB, which they should be by default), it'll just be that the SQL statement will autocommit.

Comment: Because inserting a single row does not require a transaction.
Also under load is GREATLY increases the chance of a deadlock occurring because while a transaction is happening it can lock tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable transactions for the whole application, but you can do it for individual calls of methods like `save` and `remove`. To do this, pass the `transaction` option with a value of false.
For example:

```
userRepository.save(users, { transaction: false });
userRepository.remove(users, { transaction: false });
```

See for details [Additional options](https://typeorm.io/repository-api#additional-options) section.